# how to select rows with duplicate content with criteria in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

As you can see in the Data table, the ID is not unique, I would like to select the unique ID and Value with the latest date. The results looks like the Results table. Can anyone provide some VBA codes in excel to help with? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Data Table

```
ID      Dates       Value  
10021   1/1/2012    591.00  
10021   1/1/2014    591.00  
10021   8/1/2015    621.00  
10060   1/1/2006    240.00  
10060   1/1/2011    385.00  
10060   1/1/2014    446.00  
10060   8/1/2015    468.00  
10061   1/1/2006    501.00  
10061   1/1/2011    658.00  
10061   1/1/2014    796.00  
10061   8/1/2015    836.00
```

Results Table

```
ID  Dates   Value  
10021   8/1/2015    621.00  
10060   1/1/2014    468.00  
10061   8/1/2015    836.00
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why VBA? Why not use the Remove duplicates command? Why not use the macro recorder while using that command? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Isn't `468.00` the latest for `10060`?

Comment: @findwindow You are right. Sorry about that.

Comment: @teylyn I sorted by Dates, from newest to oldest, I then used Remove duplicates command. I think it automatically keep the first one, which is the newest one! Please forgive my ignorance. I never used the Remove Duplicates command before and do not know Excel can do that. I am glad I learned something new! BTW, I do not use "macro recorder while using that command", can you give some hint on that? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted by Dates, from newest to oldest, I then used Remove duplicates command. I think it automatically keep the first one, which is the newest one